# Accessing methods of a child object, through a Dictionary

Tags: c#

New programmer, using C# and VB 2015, first time post so please be gentle!

Basically I am using Dictionary for the first time, and I am trying to access the method useMedPack() which inside my MedPack class, which is a child of Item, which is being created when adding it to my Dictionary. The problem is that it says:

****EDIT**** I feel like I should have added the Item class in first time round (now added to the bottom). Following some awesome suggestions, I casted using   ((MedPack)inventory["MedPack"]).useMedPack(); and it now works as intended! Although some of the feedback has been great and I have learned a lot from everyones suggestions! :)

> 'Item' does not contain a definition for useMedPack();.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<String, Item> inventory = new Dictionary<String, Item>();

            inventory.Add("MedPack", new MedPack("MedPack", 1));

            MedPack.pickUpMedPack(inventory);

            //THIS IS THE PROBLEM inventory["MedPack"].useMedPack();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MedPack : Item
    {

        private int healthReturn = 10;

        public MedPack() : base()
        {

        }

        public MedPack(String itemName, int itemQuantity) : base(itemName, itemQuantity)
        {

        }

        public void useMedPack() 
        {
            decreaseQuantity(1);
        }

        public static void pickUpMedPack(Dictionary<String, Item> inventory)
        {

            if (!inventory.ContainsKey("MedPack"))
            {

                inventory.Add("MedPack", new MedPack("MedPack", 1));

                Console.WriteLine("You found a MedPack! It was added to the inventory");


            }
            else
            {

                inventory["MedPack"].increaseQuantity(1);

                Console.WriteLine("You found ANOTHER MedPack! It was added to the inventory");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Item
    {

```
    private String itemName;
    private int itemQuantity;


    public Item(String itemName, int itemQuantity)
    {

        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;

    }

    public Item()
    {

    }

    public void increaseQuantity(int increaseQuantity)
    {

        this.itemQuantity += increaseQuantity;

    }

    public void decreaseQuantity(int increaseQuantity)
    {

        this.itemQuantity -= increaseQuantity;

    }


    public String getName()
    {

        return this.itemName;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {

        this.itemName = name;

    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {

        return this.itemQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int x)
    {

        this.itemQuantity = x;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: is useMedPack a member of Item?

Comment: Why is your dictionary not of type Dictionary<string, MedPack>?

Comment: have you tried casting?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was trying to use Item so that I could have Medpack/StimPack/Booze/other items as childs, so that the dictionary could store all of them, does that make sense?

Comment: Unrelated, but methods in C# should be PascalCased rather than camelCased.  See [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That makes sense, but it looks like the answer I up voted now includes more in regards to casting... I found this channel ages ago and I highly recommend you check it out if you are new:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lisiwUZJXqQ&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSX7fVd4OUFp_ODd86H0ZIY&index=21

Although some people believe this guy talks too fast, I don't find him too bad - that said I definitely remember rewinding occasional bits he raced over.

Comment: I suggest you check out his OO and design pattern videos, not just the Learn in 1 videos. He uses Java for the design patterns tutorial, the concepts are pretty much universal and can be applied to other languages by just searching for the equivalent syntax.

Comment: @Joekomino cheers, will definitely check it out, was originally doing a Udemy course on Java so I have been doing a mixture of Java and C# (with MonoGame), so I pretty used to switching between the languages now. I always appreciate more learning material!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dictionary stores objects of type `Item`.  There's no guarantee that an arbitrary `Item` will be a `MedPack` therefore you can't directly call `useMedPack` on it.

If, in your case, you *know* that the item is a `MedPack` you can just cast it:

```
((MedPack)inventory["MedPack"]).useMedPack();
```

or in two lines:

```
MedPack mp = (MedPack)inventory["MedPack"];
mp.useMedPack();
```

If, at run time, the item is *not* a `MedPack`, you'll get an exception.

If you want a single method that can be applied to *all* item types ,then define it in `Item` and override it in the sub-classes as necessary:

in `Item`:

```
public virtual void UseItem()
{
    // base implementtaion
}
```

in `MedPack`:

```
public override void UseItem()
{
    // implementation specific to MedPack
}
```

Comment: It would be good to note here that if you are trying to use polymorphism, a better solution would be to add a `UseItem()` method to the base class (`Item`) and override/implement it in the derived class.

Comment: @tehDorf True, but there's lots of room for improvement here - `MedPack` having a static method that takes an `Inventory`, etc.

Comment: That makes sense! I will try that out, thanks for the advice :) I am still pretty much a noob so these responses are giving me plenty to investigate

Comment: @DStanley Good point, he may want to take this over to Code Review as well :). I was just saying that it looks like his intention was to get it working with polymorphism, not how to call a method that is not in the base class.

Comment: @DStanley casting worked great, and I now have the functionality I was looking for, tested and fully working, however I am now going to redo the classes using overrides instead, as I understand Casting isn't always the best option, instead I'll opt for, eh, better code :D

Comment: @DavidManuel Very good.  Yes, you should avoid casting if at all possible. Better to use generics, polymorphism or other patterns to avoid runtime errors.